# Can i use a bokashi system to make mushroom compost?

Tags: compost

Can I use a bokashi system to make mushroom compost? if it is possible, what is the recipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really. Mushroom compost is always based on manure (horse, preferably) and a source of carbohydrate, with, if it's a good compost, bloodmeal. Bokashi composting is a fermenting process which deals well with kitchen/food waste and scraps, none of which (I hope!) will be manure.